# Are there mountain rings?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, matrix

## Challenge

Given a matrix of positive integers, determine if there are any "rings" of mountains. The formal definition for this challenge is: given a matrix of positive integers, is there any positive integer `n` for which there is a closed ring of cells in the matrix that are strictly greater than `n` such that all cells enclosed in the ring are less than or equal to `n`.

Let's take a truthy example:

```
3 4 5 3
3 1 2 3
4 2 1 3
4 3 6 5
```

If we set `n` to `2`:

```
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

As we can clearly see, the `1`s along the edge form a ring.

We define a ring as an ordered collection of cells where adjacent cells in the collection are also adjacent (edge or corner) on the grid. Additionally, the ring must contain at least 1 cell inside of it; that is, attempting to edge-only BFS-floodfill the entire matrix excluding the cells in the collection and never traversing a cell in the collection must miss at least one cell.

## Truthy Test Cases

```
4 7 6 5 8 -> 1 1 1 1 1
6 2 3 1 5 -> 1 0 0 0 1 (n = 3)
6 3 2 1 5 -> 1 0 0 0 1
7 5 7 8 6 -> 1 1 1 1 1

1 3 2 3 2
1 6 5 7 2
1 7 3 7 4
1 6 8 4 6

1 3 1
3 1 3
1 3 1

7 5 8 7 5 7 8 -> if you have n = 4, you get an interesting ridge shape around the top and right of the grid
8 4 4 2 4 2 7
6 1 8 8 7 2 7
5 4 7 2 5 3 5
5 6 5 1 6 4 5
3 2 3 2 7 4 8
4 4 6 7 7 2 5
3 2 8 2 2 2 8
2 4 8 8 6 8 8

5 7 6 8 6 8 7 -> there is an island in the outer ring (n = 4), but the island is a ring
5 3 2 4 2 4 7
6 3 7 8 5 1 5
8 2 5 2 8 2 7
8 3 8 8 8 4 7
6 1 4 1 1 2 8
5 5 5 5 7 8 7

150 170 150
170 160 170
150 170 150
```

## Falsy Test Cases

```
1 2 3 2 1 -> this is just a single mountain if you picture it graphcially
2 3 4 3 2
3 4 5 4 3
2 3 4 3 2
1 2 3 2 1

4 5 4 3 2 -> this is an off-centered mountain
5 6 5 4 3
4 5 4 3 2
3 4 3 2 1

1 1 1 1 1 -> this is four mountains, but they don't join together to form a ring
1 2 1 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1
1 1 1 1 1

3 3 3 3 3 -> there is a ring formed by the `3`s, but the `4` in the middle is taller so it doesn't qualify as a mountain ring
3 1 1 1 3
3 1 4 1 3
3 1 1 1 3
3 3 3 3 3

3 4 4 4 3
4 4 3 4 4
3 3 3 3 4
4 4 3 4 4
3 4 4 4 3

1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
22 23 24 25 26
```

## Rules

- Standard Loopholes Apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes in each language is declared the winner of its language. No answers will be accepted.
- The input may be taken as any reasonable form for a matrix of positive integers
- The output may be given as any two reasonable, consistent, distinct values indicating [true] or [false].

Comment: For what `n` is the third "truthy" test case actually truthy? **[1,2]**?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The ring of 3s are adjacent by corner. So, yes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 38 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ẇ€Z$⁺Ẏµ,ZẈ>2ẠµƇµḊṖZƊ⁺FṀ<,Z.ịḊṖ$€Ɗ€ƊȦ)Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVO9TsMwEN77FB66IFmoju06SIiRh0iUkQX1BdiAgVZFYmRmYmKtRMNWpIrXcF8knO8nTls6IFmn@PPn777zXW5vZrO7rovt0@7xoxrvHtrYvmxWuort4qqI7dtmtZ1vVvFzGdev1XYJhOu4vr/U1Xn8eiZ4DFfhJIWf9zM47b7nsOu6eqRUXTutglZTrbxWZaNVDZ@FVlYrAxgDFjEBApIhlnCxaTTqGGGlmFhGVEMGAh5DdJkBIu5Ix6Rz8mCZiiiTyEGJUmwlsUjKoQ2KgQswyKYLAnskEeBR3zNMvsmeYzgXRwVwSso3RYylMrvESAvZ5IucUOmllOSlD/2RmLSDelwuyUoLfO5MKcX0yQPDVtKWeyIGdwaXmPSo4AdNDn1z/ASoIQU/wb7g95RQBPYYuaf92xl@B4uZZVhoRx2xfzL2NVg432FW3zzROWJk1YGOkTcwbNDIwBcZ@BeDhS2m4pVn2uTJtoMmnGQMNLKwk2XzIDJ8eM2dYgw0Dnvl8u9PU3ABlqjHyVwqO1lNzpFn0jgB0wDVALdAbpGmP712mt80mPCjj5pf)

Outputs **1** if the matrix contains mountain ranges, **0** otherwise.

### How it works (slightly outdated)

I may be able to shorten the code a bit, so this section will probably undergo heavy editing.

**The helper link**

```
,Z.ịḊṖ$€Ɗ€ – Helper link. Let S be the input matrix.
,Z         – Pair S with its transpose.
        Ɗ€ – For each matrix (S and Sᵀ), Apply the previous 3 links as a monad.
  .ị       – Element at index 0.5; In Jelly, the ị atom returns the elements at
             indices floor(x) and ceil(x) for non-integer x, and therefore this
             returns the 0th and 1st elements. As Jelly is 1-indexed, this is the
             same as retrieving the first and last elements in a list.
    ḊṖ$€   – And for each list, remove the first and last elements.
```

For example, given a matrix in the form:

```
A(1,1) A(1,2) A(1,3) ... A(1,n)
A(2,1) A(2,2) A(2,3) ... A(2,n)
A(3,1) A(3,2) A(3,3) ... A(3,n)
...
A(m,1) A(m,2) A(m,3) ... A(m,n)
```

This returns the arrays (the order doesn't matter):

```
A(1,2), A(1,3), ..., A(1,n-1)
A(m,2), A(m,3), ..., A(m,n-1)
A(2,1), A(3,1), ..., A(m-1,1)
A(2,n), A(3,n), ..., A(m-1,n)
```

Long story short, this generates the outermost rows and columns, with the corners removed.

**The main link**

```
Ẇ€Z$⁺Ẏµ,ZẈ>2ẠµƇµḊṖZƊ⁺FṀ<ÇȦ)Ṁ – Main link. Let M be the input matrix.
Ẇ€                           – For each row of M, get all its sublists.
  Z$                         – Transpose and group into a single link with the above.
    ⁺                        – Do twice. So far, we have all contiguous sub-matrices.
     Ẏ                       – Flatten by 1 level.
      µ      µƇ              – Filter-keep those that are at least 3 by 3:
       ,Z                      – Pair each sub-matrix S with Sᵀ.
         Ẉ                     – Get the length of each (no. rows, no. columns).
          >2                   – Element-wise, check if it's greater than 2.
            Ạ                  – All.
               µ          )  – Map over each sub-matrix S that's at least 3 by 3
                ḊṖ           – Remove the first and last elements.
                  ZƊ         – Zip and group the last 3 atoms as a single monad.
                    ⁺        – Do twice (generates the inner cells).
                     FṀ      – Flatten, and get the maximum.
                       <Ç    – Element-wise, check if the results of the helper
                               link are greater than those in this list.
                         Ȧ   – Any and all. 0 if it is empty, or contains a falsey
                               value when flattened, else 1.
                           Ṁ – Maximum.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>224</s> ... 161 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
p=prod
~ =map
^ =reverse o$
@ =transpose o~(^o^)
$l=:[h:t]|h>1=l=[1: $t]
$e=e
?m=p[p(~p(limit(iterate(@o@)(~(~(\a|a>b=2=0))m))))\\n<-m,b<-n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBNi8IwEIbv@RWB7aGFFKzaD8Soh93DgjePtYVY4xpoPohRdkH60zc7aRfMMJN5eJPJS7qeM@WlPt97jiUTygtptHX44M4f6kFg24sTMtRYfUYDppIZ1GJq@YPbG8c6QjtMnWXqZnTgIW51m6Cop6v6unLN87rJaE/rbIUj16CIU462kpraxIOJeyGFi4Xjljke7/QuiQeII3uyzYnO6SxJZALreFTrVJLTOlWNPzhmHXoDu86Kb0xxXZckJxUJtSRVQ@qKLCHmY5bABclADycmzkEJfU4WJB@5gD6Duhx5AVrIEjjMC9MKoPHOv15Bhgh6eCnML0JtGjB3uavOCa3A3hbRF06m/W936dnXzaefe//@o5gU3QTTh/v06vPZTP4B)

Defines the function `? :: [[Int]] -> Int`, returning `0` if there is an ring, and `1` otherwise.

Works by turning the matrix into `2`s for mountains and `0`s for valleys, then floods in with `1`s until the result stops changing. If any `0`s still exist for any mountain height, the product will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 302 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.some((b,i)=>b.some((n,j)=>(Q=(W=(i,j,f)=>[a.map((b,I)=>b.map((t,J)=>I==i&J==j)),...a+0].reduce(A=>A.map((b,I)=>b.map((t,J)=>f(I)(J)&&(A[I-1]||b)[J]|(A[I+1]||b)[J]|b[J-1]|b[J+1]|t))))(i,j,I=>J=>a[I][J]<=n)).some((b,i)=>b.some((d,j)=>d&&!i|!j|!Q[i+1]|b[j+1]==b.b))<!/0/.test(W(0,0,I=>J=>!Q[I][J]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNb@IwEL37V5gL2CKkMbFJKtWRuCAll6qnHrJIJJCuElGCSHbVA/@dnZkYCtLuxnLGM/P85stN8bvotqf62M8O7a66rOylsEnhd@1nJUTp1dImpdMOXgOaeLPi3Yraa7wPUPPC/yyOCE0JSkrvZaCk1tbjzNpGSs/3/WIarP1Ttfu1rcTSJst/3vsQqRSZHI/FMk9nan0@lzLP1mdUp99qmWfoBIHGXsJHWaU2yaCEPF0D6sUepPxrNTuqZjcej@rzqDmP3vJ6SnQNCGtLv5TyZfQUPPl91fXiXQRe4LgBS@QY8rJ6fbVfNtm2h67dV/6@/SlW4svvjvu6F5Mfh4mk2nqb9Fcjd7Zjceqq1b4tKHkGTGITcs0ND1nIFZ@D1PBXJEO@4GbjYJpHqPKYLRAGEAOnkMCGReCJeMwXV7giF2ym6FpEpwgsEddkiyHuA1xRCiGj89WBxDF39AzvYH64IwivwIde1AzXdIJaICFDUTEOVMdcLhgbWJBjAWdCky@GjStmyI2cmF98TcJQ7YMRA4UuBU1JhFS5oT7ElMBAGIEWElnskAqkojbHwDIsvBvd2mACriLYJmAkF6SzOztA7yc/meE3ubVxqFMxlJr6P8wXzne2G@57usa5hsZpegDmjuIBrrhbxESb/de2uT02t2jWiuYdur482tza3L1S7dLSVIe@gfSDzeE2Dy3R9Fqx189cQT8hCuQH8SCwYQpGE3EVc/XM5wGbw1OAcmHCMEp8opc/)

Checks if flowing from a point can't reach the border, while border can walk to every point